# How to Build Libgcc of GCC compiler

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, libgcc

Is there any way to build libgcc without building gcc compiler?

I have tried to run configure script of libgcc but it says ../../gcc/libgcc.mvars is missing.

My basic need is to build libgcc for multiple platforms with multiple configurations for various versions of libgcc.

Answer (score 4):

Not reliably, because the GCC build system is quite monolithic and fragile.

The quickest way to get the libgcc's built is to configure and build with something like the following:

```
../gcc-src/configure --target=$TARGET --enable-languages=c
make all-target-libgcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

You might have to `make all-gcc` first, not sure if the dependencies are set up correctly.

Comment: consider platform A, 64-bit as host. Platform B defaults to 64-bit, but `-m32` is supported. Any idea how to go about and build the `libgcc` for the `-m32` target? Simply adding `CFLAGS=-m32` to the make invocation would end up overwriting the original (`-m64`) libraries.

Comment: @0xC0000022L If you use `--enable-multilib` this may just work. I'm not sure though, as I have always built libgcc as part of the whole GCC thing.

Comment: yep, unfortunately that alone is not enough. There's more magic sauce needed, it seems. But thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Essentially nothing stops you from configuring/building it twice, once with `CC='gcc -m32'` and once with `CC='gcc -m64'`...

Comment: Seems like you should use either `--disable-multilib` or `--enable-multilib` since it says "configure: error: I suspect your system does not have 32-bit development libraries (libc and headers). If you have them, rerun configure with --enable-multilib. If you do not have them, and want to build a 64-bit-only compiler, rerun configure with --disable-multilib."